# How does an assembly debugger manipulates registers?

Tags: debugging, assembly, dosbox

How does the debugger manipulate registers on a working CPU?

i am using nasm and afd with dosbox (don't know and can't use any alternative setup cuz my university requires this setup). running win 10.
really new to assembly. read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965575/how-is-it-possible-to-read-the-cpu-registers-using-a-debugger-running-on-the-sam)
but everything just went over my head. so please explain like i am 5. maybe some references to starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger built-in to DOSBOX is easy: it has a side-channel to access the entire machine state.

Under a multitasking OS, there are system calls like Linux `ptrace` that can manipulate the state of another process.

Under DOS, the debugger has to insert itself into a different region of memory than the program being debugged.  The x86 ISA itself has debug features like TF in FLAGS (Trace Flag) for single stepping.

Once the debugger has control of the CPU (i.e. the CPU is executing debugger code), it can save the old values of registers somewhere (on the stack or in static locations).

It can restore them all (with `mov` instructions) and return to the program being debugged by using an `iret` that loads CS:IP and FLAGS from memory.  SS:SP has to be valid for this to work (the return info will be right below the `SS:SP` of the process being debugged).  So real-mode DOS debugging is "intrusive", and will clobber space below SS:SP.  Unlike under a multitasking OS with virtual memory.

Another way to get back to the process being debugged without using any registers (i.e. after restoring everything) would be a `far jmp cs:[mem]` using an absolute addressing mode.  But that can't restore FLAGS, so it won't work if you want to have TF set when you resume execution of the process being debugged.

Comment: so essentially the debugger in DOS waits for its turn (like normal processes) and afterwards restores the registers' previous state? but what can't understand is, when i am running the afd debugger, i observe the registers and memory after each command, that takes some time so does the debugger takes control of the CPU every time I execute a command (i.e. several time in one program) or is there something i am missing?something about interrupts (haven't read about them yet)? also, i am using 'Advanced Fullscreen Debugger' AFD, it's not the same as "The debugger built-in to DOSBOX" , right?

Comment: @Awaisome: no.  DOS doesn't have a process scheduler.  A debugger like Turbo Debugger or AFD running *inside* DOSBOX would install an interrupt handler for the debug interrupt.  It sets software breakpoints by replacing a byte at the start of an instruction with an `int3` instruction. that triggers the debug exception.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/INTn:INTO:INT3:INT1.html

Comment: [read this](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/interrupt). has a great video on interrupts and I/O.so from what i make of this is if i have two instructions [mov ax,5] and [add ax,6] it's gonna set a break point/send int3h before each instruction? i.e. get the copy of the register values after executing the first instruction, use iret and load the previous state from stack until i execute the next statement and so on? is this efficient? can't the debugger get a copy of the cpu state and simulate?

Comment: @Awaisome: single-stepping is quite slow compared to normal execution (like hundreds to thousands of times slower), but still plenty fast for interactive use.  Yes if you want a detailed record of every instruction run in a process, you might be better off simulating it or using binary instrumentation than using `iret` with TF set after every insn.  But every keypress triggers an interrupt, and thousands to millions of instructions run before a character is displayed on screen, depending on how complicated the software is (DOS in text mode vs. typing in Chrome under X11 under Linux.)

Comment: [read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_flag), beginning to wrap my head around it. hadn;t gotten to read this part of my book yet  so in short, does AFD use **single stepping or the iret procedure** (whatever is's called)? also, is it possible for a single cpu to use **polling with some devices and interrupts with others** seeing as they both have their benefits.